# How to determine post request inputs using javascript

Tags: javascript, python

I am trying to login to a website using python but not having much success. Whenever I post my credentials, I get a 200 response but I'm redirected to the login screen. I think this is because the website's login is using javascript that requires more than just a username and password in the post command, but I'm not sure how to parse it to fix my login code.

This is my python code:

```
s = requests.session()
login_url = "example.com"
result = s.get(login_url)
payload = {
    "user_login": "xx", 
    "user_pass": "xx"
}
print(payload)
postresult = s.post(
    login_url, 
    data = payload,
    allow_redirects=True
)
```

Here's what the input form looks like:

```
<div id="loginForm">
        <ul>
            <li>
                <label>Email:</label>
                <input class="txt" type="email" name="user_login" tabindex="1" value="">
            </li>
            <li>
                <label>Password:</label>
                <input class="txt" type="password" name="user_pass" tabindex="2">
            </li>
            <li class="submit">
                <a id="a-fgt" class="sub" href="#" tabindex="4">Forgot Password</a>
                <input type="submit" id="logSubmit" value="Login" tabindex="3" />
                <div id="rightBlock">
                    <span id="respMsg"></span>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

And here's part of the javascript code that's executing:

```
function init_login(){
    var form = document.forms.loginForm;
        $submit(form,login_request);
        $listen($('a-fgt'),'click',function(){buildForgotPassword(false);},false);

    var lgn = getCookie('login');
        if(lgn){form.user_login.value = lgn;}
        form[wordCount(form.user_login.value)?'user_pass':'user_login'].focus();

        formVal = new FormValidator(form);
}


/*---\\\ LOGIN FUNCTIONS ///---*/
    function login_request(form){
        form = validateForm(form, 'user_pass');
        $post("/JSMX/admin_login.cfc?method=login",login_response,form);
    }
```

Comment: Are you posting to `www.example.com/JSMX/admin_login.cfc?method=login` ?

Comment: You can sniff your browser's HTTP request to see what's goin' on. Go to the login page and press F12. Go to Network, check "Persist logs", then login and watch the fireworks. Click on the relevant request and you can see if there's any extra data you need.